# Mysterious error when combining lead function, second window function and column alias

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions, column-alias

Consider the following query:

```
select
   corpus_date as alias
   ,lead(word, 1) over (partition by corpus order by word_count desc) lead
   ,max(word_count) over (partition by corpus) max_word_count

from
   [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]

where corpus='othello' and length(word) > 10

limit 5
```

This gives me the error message `Field 'alias' not found.` But `alias` is only used as an alias in this query. Note also that the error disappears if I comment out either the alias, or the `lead` function or the `min` function. The error also disappears if I replace `lead` with another window function like `min` or `sum`, while the error remains if I likewise replace `max`, so the necessary ingredients appear to be

- the `lead` function
- another window function
- an aliased field

I would like to know what it is about how these functions work internally that causes this mysterious error.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You can submit it: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: Thanks, I submitted it. But I would still like to understand what causes this.

Comment: we're seeing a couple of other similar errors with column aliases; I'll add this example to the internal investigation bug.