# Alias of window function field causing a "not found" error when used in HAVING and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, alias, window-functions

Consider the following BigQuery query:

```
SELECT
    tn.object AS object_alias,
    tn.attribute1 AS attribute1_alias,
    tn.attribute2 AS attribute2_alias,
    tn.score AS score_alias,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute1_alias, attribute2_alias ORDER BY score_alias DESC) AS row_num_alias
FROM
    [datasetName.tableName] tn
HAVING # also causes error when using WHERE
    row_num_alias <= 20
```

In this query, the reference to the `row_num_alias` field in the `HAVING` clause is causing the following error: `Field 'row_num_alias' not found.` I get the same error when replacing the `HAVING` clause with a `WHERE` clause, and it seems like this error is thrown for *all* window functions.

Is this a bug in BigQuery? Or is there another error in my query?

Possibly related:

- [Mysterious error when combining lead function, second window function and column alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887946/mysterious-error-when-combining-lead-function-second-window-function-and-column)
- https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=336&q=window%20alias

One workaround is to just convert this to a subquery and to move the `WHERE` clause outside the subquery (see below), but this seems cumbersome (and hopefully isn't necessary).

```
SELECT
    object_alias,
    attribute1_alias,
    attribute2_alias,
    score_alias,
    row_num_alias
FROM
    (SELECT
        tn.object AS object_alias,
        tn.attribute1 AS attribute1_alias,
        tn.attribute2 AS attribute2_alias,
        tn.score AS score_alias,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY attribute1_alias, attribute2_alias ORDER BY score_alias DESC) AS row_num_alias
    FROM
        [datasetName.tableName] tn
    )
WHERE
    row_num_alias <= 20
```

Comment: Using subquery, as Gordon suggested, is the way to go in BigQuery! Btw, i dont think links you referenced in your question actually related to this question. Those are different issue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Column aliases do not work in the `WHERE` clause, even in BigQuery.  There is no guarantee that they work in the `HAVING` clause either, although some databases do support that.  Column aliases can be used in the `ORDER BY`; I think this support by the standard is part of phasing out reference-by-number.

You know the right solution, which is to use a subquery.

By the way, a `HAVING` clause with no `GROUP BY` looks very awkward.  Such a construct is often used in MySQL, but only as a work-around -- subqueries in MySQL incur much more overhead than in other databases because the optimizer is not as sophisticated.

Comment: In general, window function don't work in `WHERE` clauses.  [This answer does a good job explaining why.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997396/477563)

Comment: Thank you both for the insight. Great to know. Most of my SQL experience is in MySQL, so, as you noted, using the `HAVING` clause without the `GROUP BY` didn't seem terribly strange. Thanks again!